# How to represent the IP from addrinfo in WINAPI?

Tags: c, winapi, winsock2

How to print the ip of the server as `a.b.c.d` in WINAPI

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc < 3)
        return -1;
    WSADATA wsData;
    int result;
    struct addrinfo * client = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    result = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &ptr);
    if (result < 0 )
        return -1;

    printf("%s", inet_addr(ptr->ai_addr->sa_data));
}
```

this results in a segmentation fault when executed

Comment: Dude - follow the sample code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo.  Initialize all your variables correctly before calling getaddrinfo().  Don't forget to call WSAStartup() before, and WSACleanup() after.  Don't forget to call WSAAddressToString() if you want to print the address.  If it still fails, run in your IDE to get a stack traceback!

Comment: *"this results in a segmentation fault when executed"* - Windows doesn't raise segmentation faults. Please provide the full, unabridged error diagnostic. A debugger will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inet_addr()` converts a null-terminated string in dotted IPv4  format into its binary 32bit number representation. That number is suitable for storing in a `sockaddr_in`, for instance. That is the *opposite* of what you want.

`ptr->ai_addr->sa_data` is not an null-terminated string, which is why `inet_addr()` crashes.

To convert an IP address in a `sockaddr_...` struct, such as output from `getaddrinfo()`, into its string representation, you can use [`inet_ntop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_ntop), eg:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
        return -1;

    WSADATA wsData;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsData);
    if (result != 0)
        return -1;
    
    struct addrinfo hints, *addrs, *ptr;
    char ipStrBuf[50];
    
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    result = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &addrs);
    if (result != 0) {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    for (ptr = addrs; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        switch (ptr->ai_addr->sa_family) {
            case AF_INET: {
                struct sockaddr_in *ip4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) ptr->ai_addr;
                printf("%s", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(ip4->sin_addr), ipStrBuf, sizeof(ipStrBuf)));
                break;
            }
            
            case AFINET6: {
                struct sockaddr_in6 *ip6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) ptr->ai_addr;
                printf("%s", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(ip6->sin6_addr), ipStrBuf, sizeof(ipStrBuf)));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addrs);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`getnameinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getnameinfo), specifying the `NI_NUMERICHOST` flag, eg:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
        return -1;

    WSADATA wsData;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsData);
    if (result != 0)
        return -1;
    
    struct addrinfo hints, *addrs, *ptr;
    char ipStrBuf[50];
    
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    result = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &addrs);
    if (result != 0) {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    for (ptr = addrs; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        result = getnameinfo(ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen, ipStrBuf, sizeof(ipStrBuf), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
        if (result == 0) {
            printf("%s", ipStrBuf);
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addrs);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can use [`WSAAddressToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaddresstostringa), eg:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
        return -1;

    WSADATA wsData;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsData);
    if (result != 0)
        return -1;
    
    struct addrinfo hints, *addrs, *ptr;
    char ipStrBuf[50];
    DWORD ipBufSize;
    
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    result = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &addrs);
    if (result != 0) {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    for (ptr = addrs; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        ipBufSize = sizeof(ipStrBuf);
        result = WSAAddressToStringA(ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen, NULL, ipStrBuf, &ipBufSize);
        if (result == 0) {
            printf("%s", ipStrBuf);
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addrs);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can use [`RtlIpv4AddressToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ip2string/nf-ip2string-rtlipv4addresstostringa) and [`RtlIpv6AddressToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ip2string/nf-ip2string-rtlipv6addresstostringa), eg:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
        return -1;

    WSADATA wsData;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsData);
    if (result != 0)
        return -1;
    
    struct addrinfo hints, *addrs, *ptr;
    char ipStrBuf[50];
    
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    result = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &addrs);
    if (result != 0) {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    for (ptr = addrs; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        switch (ptr->ai_addr->sa_family) {
            case AF_INET: {
                struct sockaddr_in *ip4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) ptr->ai_addr;
                printf("%s", RtlIpv4AddressToStringA(&(ip4->sin_addr), ipStrBuf));
                break;
            }
            
            case AFINET6: {
                struct sockaddr_in6 *ip6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) ptr->ai_addr;
                printf("%s", RtlIpv6AddressToStringA(&(ip6->sin6_addr), ipStrBuf));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addrs);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `inet_addr()` on the latest version of Visual Studio and be sure to add `#pragma warning(disable:4996)`

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT did you not read my answer? `inet_addr()` does the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: I am using `InetNtopA` seems to do the job but your answer is very useful

Comment: @loaded_dypper `InetNtopA()` is the Microsoft-special version of the cross-platform `inet_ntop()`. `InetNtopA()` exists opposite `InetNtopW()` for `TCHAR` support on Windows. There is no cross-platform version of `inet_ntop()` for Unicode.